# SAS, generate (repeat) sequency number, elegant way

Tags: sas, dataset, repeat

I want to generate the dataset below. Instead of write out 1-84, Is there a better of doing this? Thanks.

```
data test; input Index @@; datalines;
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84
; run;
```

Also, I have a macro variable like the below. A better way to write it?

```
%let Term=
24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60
66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66
72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72
84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84;
```

Comment: Whatever would you want to do the second (macro variable) for?  That seems horribly unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

```
data test; 
    do index= 1 to 84;
        output;
    end;
run;

data test2; 
array num [7] (24 36 48 60 66 72 84);
    do i = 1 to dim(num);
        do j = 1 to 12 ;
            index = num[i];
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;    
proc sql noprint;
    select index into :Term separated by " " from test2;
    quit;
    %put &Term.;
```

Or alternatively without using a dataset:

```
data _null_; 
length term $3000;
array num [7] (24 36 48 60 66 72 84);
    do i = 1 to dim(num);
        do j = 1 to 12 ;
            term = catx(" ",term,num[i]);
        end;
    end;
call symput('Term',term);
run;
%put &Term.;
```

If you are incrementing in even steps you can just use `by` in a loop e.g.

```
data _null_; 
length term $3000;
    do index= 24 by 12 to 84;
        do i = 1 to 12 ;
            term = catx(" ",term,index);
        end;
    end;
call symput('Term',term);
run;
%put &Term.;
```